# How to equate lists in prolog?

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I have the following code, which flattens a tree into a list

```
tree_list(leaf(Leaf)) --> [Leaf].
tree_list(node1(Leaf, Node)) -->
        [Leaf],
        tree_list(Node).
tree_list(node2(Leaf, Node1, Node2)) -->
        tree_list(Node1),
        [Leaf],
        tree_list(Node2).
tree_list(node3(_, Node1, Node2, Node3)) -->
        tree_list(Node1),
        tree_list(Node2),
        tree_list(Node3).
```

Sample query and answer:

```
?- phrase(tree_list(node3(1,
                     node1(2, leaf(1)),
                     node2(3, leaf(1), leaf(1)),
                     node1(4, leaf(1)))), Ls).
Ls = [2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1].
```

---

I wrote a piece of code which matches to see if two lists have the same list of elements.

```
treeMatch([], []).
treeMatch([Th| Tt], [Ah| At]) :- Th is Ah, treeMatch(Tt, At).
```

The above simply goes through a list, checking to see that each index from both lists have the same element till they hit the empty list.

---

Trying the code with `treeMatch([2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1], [2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1])` returns true.

But, if I try it with

```
treeMatch([2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1], phrase(tree_list(node3(1,
                     node1(2, leaf(1)),
                     node2(3, leaf(1), leaf(1)),
                     node1(4, leaf(1)))), Ls)).
```

I get false. Is there a way to retrieve the value of Ls and insert it directly to treeMatch to allow it to work?

Comment: You talk about ```treeMatch``` checking if the lists have the same elements. But using ```is/2```, you check if ```Ah``` arithmetically evaluates to ```Th```. Therefore ```treeMatch([2], [1+1])``` will succeed, but neither will ```treeMatch(X,foo)``` nor ```treeMatch(2,X)``` (the first because foo is no arithmetic expression and the second because evaluation can only be done on ground terms). Is this the expected behaviour? My suspicion is that you actually want to check ```L1 = L2```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `threeMatch/2` in a wrong mode.

If you call

```
treeMatch([2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1], phrase(tree_list(node3(1,
                     node1(2, leaf(1)),
                     node2(3, leaf(1), leaf(1)),
                     node1(4, leaf(1)))), Ls))
```

you ask if the list `[2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1]` is equal to the struct `phrase(tree_list(node3...`, not if it's equal to `Ls`.

You should split the call in 2 calls, as follows

```
phrase(tree_list(node3(1,
                       node1(2, leaf(1)),
                       node2(3, leaf(1), leaf(1)),
                       node1(4, leaf(1)))), Ls),
treeMatch([2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1], Ls)
```

so the first call (`phrase/2`) unifies `Ls` with `[2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1]` and `treeMatch/2` verifies that `[2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1]` match with `Ls`.

**-- EDIT --**

The OP write

> I tried it with your method and got ?- treeMatch([2, 3, 4], E). ERROR: user://3:74: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated .

Suggestion: call `treeMatch(E, [2, 3, 4])` or (better, I suppose) modify `treeMatch/2` as follows

```
treeMatch([H | Tt], [H | At]) :- treeMatch(Tt, At).
```

If you use `is/2` (`Th is Ah`) you impose one direction in your clause: the first argument can be unified with the value of the second but the second can't be unified with  the value of the first.

Comment: I tried it with your method and got `?- treeMatch([2, 3, 4], E).
ERROR: user://3:74:
        is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
`. Does that mean that E was not unified to [2, 3, 4]?

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh - improved my answer; hope this helps.